# Creating user defined function in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
miles_per_hour = float(input())
minutes_traveled = float(input())

print(f'Miles: {mph_and_minutes_to_miles(miles_per_hour, 
minutes_traveled):f}')
```

I need to create user defined function for this input program but I don't know how to define the mph_and_minutes_to_miles. I cannot change this portion of the program.

I tried:

```
def calculate_hours_traveled(minutes_traveled):
hours_traveled = minutes_traveled / 60.0
return hours_traveled

def calculate_miles_traveled(miles_per_hour, hours_traveled):
miles_traveled = hours_traveled \* miles_per_hour
return miles_traveled

mph_and_minutes_to_miles = miles_traveled
return mph_and_minutes_to_miles
```

but it still doesn't work. I have sample inputs and outputs:

70.0 for mph
100.0 for minutes traveled

output should be:

Miles: 116.666667

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're close; you just have to define the `mph_and_minutes_to_miles` function that first calls `calculate_hours_traveled` to convert the minutes to hours, then calls `calculate_miles_traveled` to get the distance travelled from the speed and the number of hours.

```py
def calculate_hours_traveled(minutes_traveled):
    return minutes_traveled / 60.0

def calculate_miles_traveled(miles_per_hour, hours_traveled):
    return hours_traveled * miles_per_hour

def mph_and_minutes_to_miles(mph, mins):
    return calculate_miles_traveled(mph, calculate_hours_traveled(mins))
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should try the following code (you need to define "mph_and_minutes_to_miles" first, and then return the right subjects) :

```
def calculate_hours_traveled(minutes_traveled):
hours_traveled = minutes_traveled / 60.0
return hours_traveled

def calculate_miles_traveled(miles_per_hour, hours_traveled):
miles_traveled = hours_traveled \* miles_per_hour
return miles_traveled

def mph_n_mins_to_miles(miles_per_hour, mins_traveled):
hours_traveled = calculate_hours_traveled(minutes_traveled)
miles_traveled = calculate_miles_traveled(miles_per_hour, 
hours_traveled)
return mph_n_mins_to_miles
```

After that you can add the code you provided above on the top and call the function:

```
miles_per_hour = float(input())
minutes_traveled = float(input())

print(f'Miles: {mph_n_mins_to_miles(miles_per_hour, 
minutes_traveled):f}')
```

Thanks

Comment: as your code written it is not indentation correctly please format your code.